# drf-spectacular's extend_schema not working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

I recently migrated from `drf-yasg` to `drf-spectacular` on my project, but the `@extend_schema` decorator does not seems to add any information to my generated schema :

- `views.py`

```py
class SearchView(GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.CriterionSerializer
    
    
    @extend_schema(
        methods=['post'],
        summary="Find patients according to search query.",
        description="Search for patients related to Documents found with the given query.",
        request=PolymorphicProxySerializer(
            component_name='Criterion',
            serializers=[
                    serializers.TextCriterionSerializer, serializers.GroupCriterionSerializer,
            ],
            resource_type_field_name='type',
        )
    )
    @action(detail=False, methods=['POST'])
    def fetch(self, request):
        serializer = serializers.CriterionSerializer(data=request.data)
        if not serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)
        
        return serializers.PatientDocumentSerializer(
            serializer.create(serializer.validated_data).fetch(), context={'request': request},
            many=True
        ).data
```

And here's the relevant part of the generated schema :

```yaml
 /search/fetch/:
    post:
      operationId: searchFetchCreate
      description: ''
      tags:
      - search
      security:
      - jwtAuth: []
      responses:
        '200':
          description: No response body
```

Here some additional information for context :

- `urls.py`

```py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'search', views.SearchView, basename='search')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls), name="search"),
]
```

- `SPECTUACULAR_SETTINGS`

```py
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'TITLE': 'API',
    'VERSION': '1.0.0',
    'CAMELIZE_NAMES': True,
    'COMPONENT_SPLIT_REQUEST': True,
    'SERVE_PERMISSIONS': ['rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'],
    'SWAGGER_UI_SETTINGS': {
        'deepLinking': True,
        'filter': True,
        'displayRequestDuration': True,
        'syntaxHighlight.activate': True,
        'syntaxHighlight.theme': 'monokai',
    },
}
```

- Versions :

```sh
$ pip3 show django drf-spectacular
Name: Django
Version: 2.2.13
[...]
---
Name: drf-spectacular
Version: 0.17.1
[...]
```

Comment: Please add a [***minimal-reproducible-example***](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to `methods=['post'],` instead of `methods=['POST'],` inside `@extend_schema`.

Comment: starting with `0.20.2`, methods are case-insensitive. so this issue should be fixed now.